How many words can be formed using all the letters of the word HONGKONG such that O and N are never together?
How many words can be formed using all the letters of the word HONGKONG such that O and N are never together ? I tried using principle of inclusion-exclusion by first calculating total ways and subtracting the ways where O,N are together but not getting correctly.
Working  - Total ways = 8!/2!2!2!
Ways in which O,N are together according to me = 2(7!/2!)-
4x6!/2
Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Welcome to MathSE. Please edit your question to show your work so that we can detect any errors you may have made.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read how to ask a good question.

Show working of the use of principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Please explain how you obtained your terms.  The error appears in the final term.

To get your question reopened, you will have to explain your reasoning. Your first two terms are correct.  However, in your third term, it looks like you only considered two disjoint pairs (a case that requires some care since the number of arrangements of G, G, NO, NO, H, K is different from the number of arrangements of G, G, NO, ON, H, K).  You also have to consider arrangements with two overlapping pairs such as NONGGHKO or three overlapping pairs such as NONOGGHK.

Here is a different approach using successive placement which may appeal.
Firstly forget about the $O's$, consider permutations of the rest with (a) $N's$ together (b) $N's$ apart, and for each case, place the $O's$ suitably
$\underline{\texttt{N's together as one letter}}$
Initial permutations with $. H . (NN) . K . G . G . = \frac{5!}{2!} =60$
Then the two $O's $ can be successively  placed  in $4\cdot5/2! = 10$ ways to give $600$ ways
$\underline{\texttt{N's apart}}$
Initial permutations with $. H . K . G . G . = 12$, and the two N's can be placed apart in $5\cdot4/2!$ ways $\rightarrow 120$ ways
$.H . N . K . N . G . G.\;$ say
The two $O's$ now have $4$ out of $7$  places barred, so can be successively placed  in $3\cdot 4/2! = 6$ ways, giving $120\cdot6 =720$ ways
Add to get answer of $1320$ ways

My answer is: 1320 (without ON and NO)
Solution outline
There are 6 different words with O, N

NONO ONON
ONNO NOON
OONN NNOO

And 12 words with other letters G, H, K. Each of this words we can split in 5 parts of  length from 0 to 4 and place them at the beginning, between letters O an N, and at the end of the word giving new word from HONGKONG. But required condition is fulfilled when 1,2,3 parts are not empty (length > 0)  for first 2 words, 2 and 4 for next two, and 3 for last two (OONN, NNOO). In first case there are 5 different splittings, 15 for second, 35 for last.
This gives 2 * 12 * (5+15+35)

Let's solve the problem step by step properly.
Step 1: Total number of arrangements of the word "HONGKONG"
The word "HONGKONG" has 8 letters, with repetitions:
O: 2 times
N: 2 times
G: 2 times
H: 1 time
K: 1 time
The total number of distinct arrangements is given by:
$ \frac{8!}{2!•2!•2!} = 5040 $

Step 2: Total number of arrangements where  and  are together
If O and N are together, treat them as a single block. This block, along with the other letters, gives the following elements to arrange:
[ON]: 1 block
HGKG: 4 distinct letters (with G repeated twice).
Thus, we now arrange these 7 blocks, where [ON]  is repeated:
$ \frac{7!}{2!•2!} = \frac{5040}{4} = 1260. $
Further, ON can be written in 2! ways.
Thus,
$ 1260 × 2! = 2520 $

Step 3: Total number of arrangements where  and  are never together
The number of arrangements where O and N are never together is given by subtracting the cases where  and  are together from the total arrangements:
Arrangements where O and N are never together = Total arrangements - Arrangements where O and N are together.
Substituting the values:
Arrangements where O and N are never together$ = 5040 - 2520 = 2520.$

Final Answer:
The number of arrangements where O and N are never together is:
$\boxed{2520}$.

Be careful: It is possible to have more than pair with an adjacent O and N such as in HONOGKGN or NONOGGHK.

Thanks. So, is 2520 wrong?

Yes, it is wrong.  This problem can be solved with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Please elaborate

There is another issue.  In step 2, there are seven objects to arrange: G, G, H, K, N, O, and the block containing the letters O and N.  There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select two positions for the Gs, $5!$ ways to arrange the five distinct objects, and $2!$ ways to arrange the letters within the block, giving $\binom{7}{2}5!2! = 7!$ such arrangements.  What you have not yet done is count arrangements in which there are two or three pairs in which N and O are adjacent.  HONOGKGN has two such pairs, while NONOGGHK has three such pairs.

Thanks. I will take that into account.

The answer is 1320 as given in the key
